# The significance of "y"

Tags: pronouns, possessives, prefixes

Regarding the pronoun "your", ignoring the singular possessive form.

Is there some significance to the "prefix" `y` or is this a coincidence?

Our:  Collective possession, including me.
Y **our**:  Collective possession, excluding me.

I'm not sure if I had an epiphany or a burnout academic experience.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't completely understand your question. Is what a coincidence? The fact that "your" contains "our"?

Comment: Pretty much, coupled with the similar but contralateral meanings.  I'm fully aware of how ridiculous the question sounds.

Comment: Think of it this way:  Defenestrate means to throw something out of the window.  De - "removal/separation from", fenestra - "window".  In this sense, I'm wondering if:  our - collective possession, ~y~ - "Excluding me".

Comment: Looking at the entries for "your" and "our" on etymonline.com, this similarity doesn't appear in their Old English forms or their reconstructed Proto-Germanic and PIE roots. "Your" was *eower* in Old English, with the PIE root **ju*, whereas "our" was, among lots of other regional forms, *ure* in Old English, with the PIE root **nes-*.

Comment: I'm not vastly familiar with word roots (my knowledge of PIE is limited to my recent wiki search). Are you suggesting that the two words have different roots and the similarity is completely coincidental?

Comment: That's exactly what he's - I think 'suggesting' is too weak a word. I'll add that this question is off-topic as etymologies are easily found from readily available resources.

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't sure how you could look up such a thing.

Comment: Type in "your meaning", try the FreeDictionary link, and look for the etymology after the definitions etc. Repeat with "our meaning". (For short words where the FreeDictionary link doesn't appear at once for "X meaning", use "Y meaning", get to the dictionaries, and use the search function there instead.)

Answer (score 8):

Looking them up in the Oxford Dictionary of English Language, *your* comes from Old English *ēower,* related to the genitive of “gē.” It states that it's of Germanic origin and is related to German *euer.*

While *our* comes from *ūre*, which is also of Germanic origin but is related to English *us* and German *unser.*

This should be proof enough that the two are not related and the similarity is some sort of coincidence.

Comment: The concrete lexemes may be traceable to distinct ancestors, but that doesn't mean that the similarity is completely accidental. A process may well be psychologically more probable if it ends in a state that *seems* as if corresponding items were related, even if linguistic inquiry can prove that they are not. The question "Why is this particular word the way it is" usually has an answer mixed from historical contingency and psychological plausibility.